# Laravel WhereIn array returns only first index results

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

```
$dean_ids = Auth::user()->dean_id; // "9,11"
$subjects = Subject::whereIn('dean_id', [$dean_ids])->select('id')->get();
```

returns only data for "9" but when i trying like this:

```
$subjects = Subject::whereIn('dean_id', [9,11])->select('id')->get(); 
//it returns all data that what i want.
```

how can i fix it?

Comment: If `$dean_ids` return string like `9,11` then instead of making array like `[$dean_ids]` explode the string using comma. Use something like: `$subjects = Subject::whereIn('dean_id', explode(',', $dean_ids))->select('id')->get();
`

Comment: realy good idea it worked, pls answer below i will mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see, this line `$dean_ids = Auth::user()->dean_id;` returns a comma-separated string. So when you make `$dean_ids` array by using `[$dean_ids]` it actually makes an array like:

```
array(
  '9,11'
)
```

Instead of

```
array(
  9,
  11
)
```

There is only one value inside the array. So what you can do just use `explode` for splitting the string by using a comma and it also returns an array.

You can try this:

```
$subjects = Subject::whereIn('dean_id', explode(',', $dean_ids))->select('id')->get();
```